# .net Setup Project: How to pass multiple CustomActionData fields

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

In a .net "Setup Project", it is possible to add one or more custom screens in the setup wizard, with fields (e.g. text boxes) where the user can enter additional installation parameters.

A custom field can then be passed to a "Custom Action" class library project, to handle the user field. The image below shows how the property "ServerName" gets mapped to the EDITB1 text field:

[image]

Within the Custom Action class, the property is accessed as follows:

```
string serverName = Context.Parameters["ServerName"];
```

Question: how can one specify multiple properties (for multiple text boxes) to the Custom Action?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per the [documentation for `CustomActionData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) regarding passing multiple values:

> Multiple values must be separated by a single space: /name1=value1 /name2=value2. If the value has a space in it, it must be surrounded by quotation marks: /name="a value"