# Passing Multiple Parameters to CustomActionData of VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is a question on Custom Actions in VB.Net.

I need to pass two Keys; the [TARGETDIR] and [OriginalDatabase] to example.dll in custom Actions.

I searched and found the general syntax as /name1=value1 /name2=value2 etc (i.e each name/value pair should be seperated by a space.

`/InstallDir="[TARGETDIR]\"` is working for me but when I want to pass both the parameters

`/InstallDir="[TARGETDIR]\" /SourceDir="[OriginalDatabase]\"` is not working. I found a similar request without a proper answer.

I would be so grateful if I could know the way to pass both these values together in CustomActionData property.

Comment: Please share the details of any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should need combine method from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [here the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999822/net-setup-project-how-to-pass-multiple-customactiondata-fields)

```
Combine(String, String)
```

Also, it said that, if your value have space in it, then must have quotation, but your string not have space, so don't need to put quotation

```
 /name1=value1 /name2=value2
```